# linq_in_php inside function

Tags: php, class, oop

I was trying to use linq_in_php, a class to query my php array in SQL syntax.
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/5893-PHP-Query-arrays-with-a-SQL-like-syntax-using-LINQ.html

This is for the cache of the actual database which returns array data and if the cache expires the same query can run directly to database.

Problem is, if I use the class in normal way in my script it works fine, but if I call the class inside a function I get error. The scenario is something like:

I have a cache file of a user table, calling that returns array like:

```
    array(
      0  =>  array(
              'uid'    => 1,
              'name'   => 'John',
              'surname'=> 'Doe'
             ),
      1  =>  array(
              'uid'    => 2,
              'name'   => 'Foo',
              'surname'=> 'Bar'
             )
    );
```

Now if I use the class like this:

```
include_once 'D3Linq.php';
$linq = new D3Linq();
$users = include 'cache/users.php'; // Loading the cache array

$linq->Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=2");

while ($usr = $linq->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($usr);
}
```

... it works fine. But if I put the same inside a function:

```
    function enCache($cache_file=''){
      include_once 'D3Linq.php';
      $linq = new D3Linq();
      $users = include 'cache/'.$cache_file.'.php'; // Loading the cache array

      $linq->Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=2");

      while ($usr = $linq->fetch_assoc()){
          $return[] = $usr;
      }
      return $return;
    }

    enCache('users'); // Call the function
```

I get error : 'users is not an array'.

If I generate the array outside function like this, this also works fine (strange!)

```
    $users = include 'cache/users.php'; // Loading the cache array

    function enCache($cache_file=''){
      include_once 'D3Linq.php';
      $linq = new D3Linq();

      $linq->Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=2");

      while ($usr = $linq->fetch_assoc()){
          $return[] = $usr;
      }
      return $return;
    }

    enCache(); // Call the function
```

From the above got a hint and tried making the array() global in several ways but no luck, and I need to get the array from inside function. New to OOP, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not what one would call a "productive response" but .... what you are doing is waste of time, and keep your distance from phpclasses.org - that site is crap

Comment: Got that link fast, so posted. Its in GitHub: https://github.com/THR/Linq-In-PHP. Also I know its not maintained and very old. Just to know the reason of the error and a good workaround.

Comment: My main point was, that what you are doing is waste of time. If you want to cache data, you should instead use APCu, which is built in feature in PHP. And if you need a fast SQL for something, you can fun SQLite database in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Linq, but from your code examples I can pretty much guess how it works.

The important thing to realize is that you're not passing your `$users` variable to Linq in any way:

```
$linq = new D3Linq();
$users = include 'cache/'.$cache_file.'.php';
$linq->Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=2");
```

Somehow, Linq knows by your `SELECT` statement that a variable called `$users` must exist. Since Linq is running in a class and does not have access to any local variables you defined just before calling the `Query()` method, it **must** be looking in the global scope.

So internally, Linq must be doing something like this:

```
public function Query($query) {
    $variable = // find whatever word comes after "FROM"
    global $$variable;

    $results = // filter $$variable to whatever comes after "WHERE"
    $results = // filter out everything that's not mentioned after "SELECT"
    return $results;
}
```

That's the only way Linq could have access to a `$users` variable. So, if you define `$users` within your `enCache` function, the `$users` variable is not in the global scope, but in your function scope. Linq will not be able to find it there, because it doesn't have access to your function scope.

What you could try is to force `$users` from your function scope into the global scope:

```
function enCache($cache_file=''){
    include_once 'D3Linq.php';
    $linq = new D3Linq();
    $users = include 'cache/'.$cache_file.'.php';

    $GLOBALS['users'] = $users;

    $linq->Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=2");

    ...etc
}
```

Although by doing that you run the risk of overwriting any global `$users` variable that already exists, so I **really** don't recommend it.

I suggest you load your cached users first thing in your application, outside any functions, like in your last example. That way you have control over when `$users` gets defined, you only have to load the file once, and you can use Linq to filter it in however many functions you want.

Comment: Thanks @rickdenhaan. $GLOBALS['users'] = $users; that worked. I tried global $users; inside function and failed, noob me. Thanks for pointing me out that superglobal.

Comment: @effone to be honest, that should be warning enough to stay away from that D3Linq as if it was plague.

Comment: @tereško Warning well taken. Was playing around reading codes of others (old habit), not for production purpose. And I was solely behind the 'superglobal' possibility, not at all behind 'D3Linq'. Appreciate your heads up.